# Angular Alias Import can not finde recognize the defined folder

Tags: angular, alias

I defined Alias import in my angular application.

the tsconfig.json looks just like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/components/*:": ["app/components/*"],
      "@app/services/*:": ["app/services/*"],
      "@app/models/*": ["app/models/*"],
      "@app/shared/components/*": ["app/shared/components/*"],
      "@app/shared/helpers/*": ["app/shared/helpers/*"]
    },
```

I can import the correct paths, if the file locates directly under the defined folder. e.g. in services folder there is a user-service, I can import this service with @app/services/userServcie correctly. 
but if there is the other folder (e.g. /auth), which is under the service folder, I can not use such as @app/services/auth/authService.ts.

I can not understand, because I have definded the paths with *

Besat Regards,

Leo

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go would be to create a `index.js/ts` file in the path and export everything from a single file. You can create several `index.ts` files in the sub-directories if needed.